# php is_array() test on $value[] - not sure why it won't register as an array

Tags: php, arrays

I am just doing some experimenting. How do I print the value of this `$chvalues[]` or test (as below) it's an array. Is it possible to print this out as-is? `$chvalues[]` (yes my input field is properly defined with `name=seminar` etc...)

```
$chvalues = array();
if (isset($_POST['seminar'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['seminar'] as $ch => $value) {
        $chvalues[] = $value;
        if(is_array('$chvalues[]')) {
            echo "Yes. It's an Array.";
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to test this:

```
if(is_array('$chvalues[]')) { ...
```

**I get this:**

```
Fatal error: Cannot use [] for reading in...
```

Comment: `[]` is for appending new values to an array. If you use it in anything but the left-hand-side of an assignment operation, it's a syntax error.

Comment: Marc B, thanks for the clarification. All the comments below were very helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You are reading the array as a string by using single quotes around it (which should just return false).
2. You should use `if(is_array($chvalues))` without the brackets.
3. `$chvalues` will always be an array, because you just assigned it to one the line before, as well as at the start of your code, before the loop.

Maybe you meant to check `$value`, or run the `is_array()` after the loop and *not* initialize `$chvalues` as an array before running the loop.

Comment: I'm not sure what's supposed to be going on here. An input with `name=seminar`, `$_POST['seminar']` will always be a string in PHP. If there are multiple, like `name=seminar[]`, then you still would need still something like `name=seminar[some_index][]` for the values of *each* `$_POST['seminar']` to be an array themselves.

Comment: ...and then still, not sure why you'd need to verify that it's an array. @OldWest, I see you've accepted the answer, but if you can tell me briefly what you're actually trying to do, I can give you some additional advice. If you've figured it out already, then GL going forward.

Comment: Thanks Wesley, I am just experimenting with arrays, so don't really have an objective right now except to learn something new.

Answer (score 1):

Following a variable by `[]` is *only* for appending new elements to the end of the array within the variable. If you want to look at the array then just use the variable itself.

```
if(is_array($chvalues)) {
   ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You only use $value[] for accessing the "top" element of the $value array, the unset next position, if you will.
Change it to $chvalues in the is_array() function.
To print an array, it depends on output. Check print_r for debugging.
Also don't use quotes as they make the array act like a string, in this case (because they are single quotes) the string '$chvalues[]' is being tested for being an array.

Answer (score 1):

Two problems here.  First, everytime you do `$chvalues[]` with empty brackets, you are appending a new empty element onto your array. So when you do:

```
if(is_array($chvalues[]))
```

You always get an empty element, never an array.

Instead you probably want:

```
if(is_array($chvalues))
```

Second problem is you cannot single-quote `'$chvalues[]'` as you have done.  It should have no quotes as in my first code block above.

Answer (score 1):

don't use $chvalues[], just $chvalues (without single quotes inside the is_array function).

```
$chvalues = array();
if (isset($_POST['seminar'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['seminar'] as $ch => $value) {
        $chvalues = $value;
        if(is_array($chvalues)) {
            echo "Yes. It's an Array.";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You really want, `is_array($chvalues)` (which will always be true in your code) or, if you're trying to find out if the last item added to `$chvalues` is an array, you should call `is_array($value)`. If you don't have that option (not sure why you wouldn't), then you can use `is_array(end($chvalues))` to test the last thing added to the array. I will warn, though, that you will need to call [`reset`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php) to iterate through `$chvalues` with `foreach`.

Of course, you could also call `$arr = array_keys( $chvalues ); is_array($chvalues[end($arr)]);`, but that gets very silly (especially since I left out the last paren originally).